# Clone reference type properties with CustomButtonCallback

Tags: asp.net, webforms, devexpress

I'm trying to follow [the DevExpress documentation example on cloning rows](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/Columns/CommandColumnCustomButtons.aspx). The basics are easy to get right, but things get tricky when you try to clone properties other than value types.

## First attempt / setting up a repro:

I've narrowed my real scenario to a small(ish) repro of the problem. The following is all part of a freshly created ASP.NET 2.0 webforms application. First, suppose these domain objects (that'll double as DTO's here too):

```
public class Qualification
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Qualification Qualification { get; set; }
}
```

Then there are two quick 'n dirty data source classes like so:

```
public class QualificationOds
{
    public static List<Qualification> Qualificiations = new List<Qualification>
    {
        new Qualification { Id = 1, Title = "Doctore" }
    };

    public List<Qualification> GetRecords()
    {
        return Qualificiations;
    }
}

public class PeopleOds
{
    public List<Person> GetRecords()
    {
        return new List<Person> 
        {
            new Person
            {
                Id = 1, 
                Name = "John Doe", 
                Qualification = QualificationOds.Qualificiations[0] 
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The default.aspx page will first register `dx` to DevExpress namespaces:

```xml
<%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.v11.1, Version=11.1.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" Namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView" TagPrefix="dx" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.v11.1, Version=11.1.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" Namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors" TagPrefix="dx" %>
```

And have a single form with this code in it:

```xml
<asp:ObjectDataSource runat="server" ID="peopleDataSource" TypeName="DevxTest.PeopleOds" SelectMethod="GetRecords" />
<asp:ObjectDataSource runat="server" ID="qualificationsDataSource" TypeName="DevxTest.QualificationOds" SelectMethod="GetRecords" />

<dx:ASPxGridView 
    runat="server"
    id="grvPeople"
    KeyFieldName="Id"
    DataSourceID="peopleDataSource"
    OnCustomButtonCallback="grid_CustomButtonCallback"
    OnInitNewRow="grid_InitNewRow">
    <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
            <EditButton Visible="true" />
            <CustomButtons>
                <dx:GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton ID="Clone" Text="Clone" />
            </CustomButtons>
        </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Name" />
        <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="Qualification.Id" >
            <PropertiesComboBox 
                DataSourceID="qualificationsDataSource"
                TextField="Title"
                ValueField="Id"
                ValueType="System.Int64" />
        </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
    </Columns>
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

The code behind contains the code to clone a row into a fresh edit form, based on aforementioned DevExpress example, like so:

```
private string[] fieldsToCopy = { "Name", "Id" };
private Hashtable valuesToClone;

protected void grid_CustomButtonCallback(object sender, ASPxGridViewCustomButtonCallbackEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ButtonID != "Clone") return;

    valuesToClone = new Hashtable();

    foreach (var fieldName in fieldsToCopy)
    {
        valuesToClone[fieldName] = grvPeople.GetRowValues(e.VisibleIndex, fieldName);
    }

    grvPeople.AddNewRow();
}

protected void grid_InitNewRow(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataInitNewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (valuesToClone == null) return;

    foreach (string fieldName in fieldsToCopy)
    {
        e.NewValues[fieldName] = valuesToClone[fieldName];
    }
}
```

This works for the `Name` property, but not so much for the `Qualification` property. It shows like this on the page:

[image: edit form with empty dropdown for Qualification]

I've also tried `"Qualification.Id"` and `"Qualification"` as field names to copy, but no dice. At any rate, I'm pretty sure it should be `"Id"` as in my example though, because the debugger shows the correct `GetRowValues` return value only for that case.

## Second attempt / custom code to handle the dropdown:

So I'm thinking I need to have some custom code to set the NewValue for a dropdown. First I create an `EditItemTemplate` for the Qualification column like so:

```xml
<EditItemTemplate>
    <dx:ASPxComboBox 
        runat="server" 
        ID="qualificationCombo" 
        DataSourceID="qualificationsDataSource"
        TextField="Title"
        ValueField="Id"
        ValueType="System.Int64" />
</EditItemTemplate>
```

And then I add this code to `grid_InitNewRow`:

```
// Attempt to set the combo box to a value:
var column = grvPeople.Columns["Qualification"] as GridViewDataColumn;
var comboBox = grvPeople.FindEditRowCellTemplateControl(column, "qualificationCombo") as ASPxComboBox;
var item = comboBox.Items.FindByValue(valuesToClone["Id"]);
item.Selected = true;
```

And it works! However, now the `Name` is no longer cloned. It looks like this:

[image: DevExpress grid after hitting "Clone" with empty Name field]

I have no clue why, but the added code has a *side-effect* causing the `NewValues` setter approach to fail.

## Bottom Line:

The bottom line is rather simple: how do I change the DevExpress example into one that can also clone reference type properties?

---

PS. I've also [cross-posted my question on the DevExpress support forum](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T207721).

Comment: You have two columns in the grid: "Name" and "Qualification.Id". When copy values in the grid_CustomButtonCallback function, you are passing following values to the ASPxGridView.GetRowValues method as the second parameter: "Name" and "Id". I suppose that the second value should be "Qualification.Id", instead of "Id".

Comment: Thanks @Uranus, your comment was spot on. I had tried that, but did so with the `EditItemTemplate` in place: then it still won't work. DevExpress support basically answered the same. I also found a solution / workaround for when `EditItemTemplate` is required, so I've compiled all that into an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention that `"Qualification.Id"` doesn't work, but you most likely tried that while the `EditItemTemplate` was there. If there is no such template then that code actually works.

To be complete, change the `fieldsToCopy` line of code to:

```
private string[] fieldsToCopy = { "Name", "Qualification.Id" };
```

And **make sure there's no `EditItemTemplate`**, then it'll work.

Alternatively, if you are stuck with a `EditItemTemplate` for some reason, there's one "solution" to make sure the ComboBox in that template gets bound to the cloned value. Make sure you hook into `OnDataBound` on the ComboBox with the following code:

```
protected void qualificationCombo_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var column = grvPeople.Columns["Qualification"] as GridViewDataColumn;
    var comboBox = grvPeople.FindEditRowCellTemplateControl(column, "qualificationCombo") as ASPxComboBox;
    var item = comboBox.Items.FindByValue(valuesToClone["Id"]);
    item.Selected = true;
}
```

This will properly set the ComboBox to the cloned value, while also leaving the `e.NewValues` approach for plain fields intact.